# System Monitor > System tab missing in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, system-monitor

I upgraded to Ubuntu 13.04 in April, but just today I observed that **System** tab is missing from **System Monitor**. I searched on internet and I didn't find too much about this fact. Did they removed it or does my system have a problem? If they removed it, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a standard feature.

If you want information of your system, open **System Settings** and choose **Details**.

Answer (score 0):

It is INDEED missing and can be found by clicking "Menu" (bottom left of computer screen) then type "System Settings" into the search bar at the top. Wait for popup and scroll to the Hardware section on the bottom and click on System Info. Should've just kept the System tab in my opinion. But the hunt is over...